# AngualrJs file is not loaded properly it got error in angular.min.js file?

Tags: angularjs

```js
    //Create the module and controller for our file 
    var app = angular.module("demoApp",[]);
    app.controller("myController", function($scope){
      $scope.message = "Hello Angularj";
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
 <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="homeData.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-contoller="myController">
 <div>
 welcome  {{message}}
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
FQF
```

[image]Helo to all,
I have to setup the AngularJs with ecllipse neon but after load the index.html file it got error in the "angular.min.js" and i have already include the library into the index.html file after hover the error it will show(Multiple markers at this line
). please tell me how to fix this?[image]

Comment: Could you show the errors from browser console

Comment: Sir i got no errors in the console please check my updated question?

Comment: Then there is no problem. "Multiple markers at this line" is not an error. It's an indication that the IDE thinks that that are multiple errors at this line. Without seeing the code and the error, we can't tell anything. But Eclipse is dumb, and there's no reason for you to think angular.min.js has an error, especially if executing your app in the browser works flawlessly.

Comment: No sir its not working for me and have print the welcome message but its not show  any message in browser?

Comment: @kapilsoni You need to add code also then only we can identity error.

Comment: Sir, check my updated code?

Comment: use this CDN for angular.min.js file https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js . After using this CDN , code is working on my side.

Comment: @Harshit kyal i have also include this CDN but not working for me same result Angular controller code is not executed please tell m how it is working in your side?

Answer (score 0):

My index.html file content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="homeData.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-contoller="myController">
    <div>
    welcome  {{message}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

home.Data.js file's content.

```
   var app = angular.module("demoApp",[]);
    app.controller("myController", function($scope){
      $scope.message = "Hello Angularj";
    });
```

Comment: Now its working for m sir..actually i have a spelling mistake (ng-contoller="myController" ) this is my mistake...

Comment: @kapilsoni that's why always upload error with code. Anyways It's good , It worked for you .